# Tutorial About IoC + NHibernate + MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, inversion-of-control, ninject

I was following up Jason Dentler's series of posts on how to use NHibernate + Ioc (Ninject) with a real world ASP.NET MVC N-Tier application. Sadly he dropped the series. Does anyone has any good suggestions of articles that cover a similar scenario? I would be very interesting in learning such things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bob Cravens [TruckTracker](http://blog.bobcravens.com/?s=trucktracker) turorials utalise MVC, NHibernate, Ninject and MySQL. I have found them to be an invaluable resource.

Comment: i just want to add pokud as IOC you want to use castle windsor you can find nice tutorial here: http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-tutorial-part-one-getting-Windsor.ashx

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about tutorials but I think that you should check [http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net](http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/MainPage.ashx). I's great reference on how to get started in no time with a web framework that includes Ioc, NHibernate and ASP.Net MVC right out the box. After installing the templates all you need to create a new project is to right click and select templyfy here :)

Comment: Thanks! Seems like a very solid architecture. But I would like to know how to achieve similar results by implementing it manually.. i mean, is for learning purposes only and before using the frameworks of S#arp Architecture I would like to know how to do such thing.