# Ninject MVC 2 - problems with EF 4 ObjectContext

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-2, ninject.web.mvc

I've been dealing with this issue for a while, and still can't seem to find a solution.  I have several repositories which wrap an EF 4 ObjectContext.  An example is below:

```
public class HGGameRepository : IGameRepository, IDisposable
{
    private readonly HGEntities _context;

    public HGGameRepository(HGEntities context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }

    // methods

    public void SaveGame(Game game)
    {
        if (game.GameID > 0)
        {
            _context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(game, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
        }
        else
        {
            _context.Games.AddObject(game);
        }

        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (this._context != null)
        {
            this._context.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

And I have the following NinjectModule:

```
public class DIModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Bind<HGEntities>().ToSelf();
        this.Bind<IArticleRepository>().To<HGArticleRepository>(); 
        this.Bind<IGameRepository>().To<HGGameRepository>();
        this.Bind<INewsRepository>().To<HGNewsRepository>();
        this.Bind<ErrorController>().ToSelf();
    }
}
```

Since I'm using the MVC 2 extension, these bindings default to `InRequestScope()`.

My problem is that the ObjectContext isn't being handled properly.  I get what's described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5275849/399584  Specifically, I get an InvalidOperationException that states:

> The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.

This happens every time I try to update an Entity.

If I set my repos to bind `InSingletonScope()` it works, but seems like a bad idea.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: For clarity, I have just one ObjectContext that I want to share with all my repos per request.

Comment: There's not any harm in using `InSingletonScope()`.

Comment: What about threading/caching?  To be honest, I'm not sure how either work in this situation (I come from PHP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify `InRequestScope()` in your module. Based on this [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/04/30/dependency-injection-in-nerddinner-app-using-ninject.aspx) the default to transient, which is why you are getting more than one context.

```
public class DIModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Bind<HGEntities>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
        this.Bind<IArticleRepository>().To<HGArticleRepository>().InRequestScope(); 
        this.Bind<IGameRepository>().To<HGGameRepository>().InRequestScope();
        this.Bind<INewsRepository>().To<HGNewsRepository>().InRequestScope();
        this.Bind<ErrorController>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
    }
}
```

Also did you add ninject to your project via nuget package manager or the old fashion way?

Comment: Nuget package.  I thought that the MVC extensions made InRequestScope() the default.  I mean, I have the following statement in NinjectWebCommon: DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));  And, according to intellisense, InRequestScope() isn't an option for me.

Comment: It has been moved to a different namespace you have to add using Ninject.Web.Common; Then you will be able to call .InRequestScope() I was under the same impression you where. But this was the only way I could get it to work. I have found some sites showing how to set the default scope but it involves inheriting the kernel and I didn't want to do that.

Comment: Almost got it.  Running into another issue.  I made a new question for it if you feel like taking a look.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/10526167/399584